# A question in differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that if $y_1$ and $y_2$ are linearly independent on $\alpha < x < \beta$ and $y$ is any function such that $y \neq 0$ on $\alpha < x < \beta$, then $yy_1$ and $yy_2$ are also linearly independent $\alpha < x < \beta$.

Need help with this proof

Comment: Once you write down the obvious equation, divide through by $y$ because its non-zero everywhere on $(\alpha, \beta)$.  Then you're done.

Comment: what is the obvious equation?

Comment: What's the definition of linear independence?

Comment: the wronskian is not equal to 0 is what we have learned

Comment: Not that $av_1 + bv_2 + \cdots = 0 \implies a=b= \cdots = 0$?

Comment: i havent seen that before we have only touched on examples no proofs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Linear Algebra Method:**

$$\begin{align}&ayy_1 + byy_2 = 0 \\ \implies &ay_1 + by_2 = 0\qquad \text{because $y\ne 0$ on $(\alpha, \beta)$} \\ \implies &a=b=0 \end{align}$$

Thus by definition $\{yy_1, yy_2\}$ is a linearly independent set.

---

**Wronskian Method:**  For this you have to assume that $y,y_1, y_2$ are all differentiable.  But in an ODEs class that's probably a safe assumption.

$$\begin{align}\begin{vmatrix}yy_1 & yy_2 \\ y'y_1 + yy_1' & y'y_2 + yy_2'\end{vmatrix} &= yy'y_1y_2+y^2y_1y_2' - yy'y_1y_2-y^2y_1'y_2 \\ &= y^2(y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2) \\ &= y^2\begin{vmatrix}y_1 & y_2 \\ y_1' & y_2'\end{vmatrix} \\ &\stackrel{(*)}{\ne} 0\end{align}$$

where $(*)$ is due to the fact that $\{y_1, y_2\}$ is a linearly independent set.

Comment: okay that wronskian method makes total sense to me

Comment: thanks a lot for your time